# Eclipse code checkstyle indentation module in java?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

i am using checkstyle.

i want to configure checkstyle so that code indentation  use 2 space. For example :-

```
while(condition) {
  if(condition) {
    while(condition)
  }
}
```

Please note the inentation is using 2 spaces. For example :- if block startted after 2 spaces.

i tried

```
     <module name="Checker">
       <module name="Indentation">
        <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
        <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
       </module>
    </module>
```

But it does not give warning on applying checkstyles when i add 4 spaces instead of 2 like below

```
 if(condition) {
        while(condition)
      }
```

I am not getting whats the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkstyle inspects code that you have. It doesn't control formatting. You need to control the formatting through Eclipse.

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
```

is where you want to start poking around.

EDIT after update of question:

The `Indentation` module belongs under the `TreeWalker` module, not the `Checker` module.

Comment: Thats a valid point that i need to use formatting if i want to do indentation.  Actually i want to display warning if somebody adds 4 spaces instead of 2 space on applying checkstyles.I updated my question.

Comment: @user3198603 Updated answer to reflect new question.

Comment: Thanks Eric.It worked could you point me to some tutorial where i can learn about these modules ?

Comment: Also if you can provide your inputs on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652606/eclipse-checkstyle-vs-formatter-vs-cleanup. It would be a help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3198603 The checkstyle homepage tells all about all the modules. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html